# Plugin is present or not, in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm working on `rails 2` application, plugins mostly.

I've two plugins, in my first plugin I've to check if the second
plugin is present, how can I do it?

For now, I'm using in `report_designer`, the first plugin.
Controller : `custom_reports`

in `custom_reports_helper` I've

```
   module CustomReportsHelper
     if File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/vendor/plugins/ReportVariablesHelper") 
       include ReportVariablesHelper
     end
   end
```

`ReportVariablesHelper` is from second plugin named `variables_for_data`

**is this a good solution or any better ways in RoR?**

Comment: What class (or module) do you include `HelperName` into?

Comment: Ok, but into what class (or module) is it included?

Comment: in the first plugin helper..

Comment: That's still not what I ask for. Where do you put your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
module CustomReportsHelper
  include ReportVariablesHelper if defined?(ReportVariablesHelper)
end
```

Comment: no problems when included in plugin, but helper actions are not getting included..